# How to retrieve data from angularFire $firebaseArray?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am using AngularFire with angular1 to get data from firebase, data is fetching successfully, but I am not able to parse the object and show the result in table on html

this is my code

```
var vm = this;
var ref = firebase.database().ref();
vm.videos = $firebaseArray(ref.child('videos'));
```

[this is the angularfire object look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wTQr.png)

this is structure of data [enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2564e09eb600cb7523af86773df94d45)

Please do not mark duplicate, and help me out.

Comment: use $scope instead of `this`

Answer (score 0):

```
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/users');
var users = $firebaseArray(ref);

users.$loaded()
.then(function(){
    angular.forEach(users, function(user) {
        console.log(user);
    })
});
```

Here's the docs on it: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/intro-to-angularfire.html#section-async-intro